# How to add a JavaScript function to an HmlGenericControl from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

From server side, I'm injecting an input and button element dynamically to client side. I also would like to inject a JavaScript function into each. The input's function should be triggered `onchange` and for the button's, should be `onclick`

This is what I've done so far:

```
//js definition
string script = @"<script>";

script += @" function OnCroquis0BtnClick() 
             {
                 var fileUp = $('#File');

                 fileUp.trigger('click');
             }"; 

script += @"function OnCroquis0FileSelected() 
            {
                txtBx = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtBx');

                var fileUpload = document.getElementById('File');

                txtBx.value = fileUpload.files[0].name;

           }";

script += @"</script>";    

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "testScript0" ,
 script);    

//html elemets definition
HtmlGenericControl input = new HtmlGenericControl(),
                   btn = new HtmlGenericControl();

input.TagName = "input";

input.ID = lbl.Text + "File";

input.Attributes["onchange"] = "OnCroquis0Fileselected()";

input.Attributes["style"] = "display: none;";

docRequeridosMainDiv.Controls.Add(input);

btn.TagName = "button";

btn.ID = "btn";

btn.InnerText = "Anejar";

btn.Attributes["onclick"] = "OnCroquis0BtnClick(); return false";

btn.Attributes["style"] = "margin-right:2%;";

docRequeridosMainDiv.Controls.Add(btn);
```

They are visible and style's are being applied, but js isn't. I figured since any html attribute is added through `Attributes["attri"]` maybe a js function could be too.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. On my version, I had function names misplaced :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "testscript0", script, false);
```

this enforces that script is executed after all the elements in the page gets loaded.